# Expectation value of square root

Tags: stochastic-processes, expectation

I want to calculate the following:

$E(\sqrt{f(x(t))})$, where $E$ denotes the expectation value.

$f$ is some function,

$x(t)$ is my stochastic process,

and i know that $\left\langle x(t)\right\rangle=0$,

$\left\langle x(t')x(t'')\right\rangle=g(t'-t'')$ and

$\left\langle x(t_1)x(t_2)...x(t_n)\right\rangle=0$ for $n \ge 3$.

My guess would be to expand the root with a taylor expansion? Is there an easier way?

Comment: The square root can just be absorbed into the arbitrary function f.

Comment: Okay then, and how to handle $E[\sqrt{x(t)}]$?

Comment: Does it make sense given that $E[x(t)]=0$ and so (presumably) $x$ is sometimes negative?

Comment: $x$ shouldn't be negative in my case

Comment: Then your averages are impossible except for one highly trivial exception.

Comment: $\left\langle\sqrt{a\exp{\left[-\int\limits_0^t\mathrm{d}s f(s)\right]}+b\exp{\left[-2\int\limits_0^t\mathrm{d}s f(s)\right]}}\right\rangle$